# Android Emulator shows glitchy screen with weird artifacts

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I installed Android studio and tried to run a virtual device, but screen turns out glitchy and nothing can be seen. All attempts to run the AVD in android studio, as well as VS Code, resulted in the same broken output.

[AVD screen upon running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPrKw.png)

For context, Im on a laptop with an Intel Core i5-8250U and a Radeon 535 graphics card. No errors seem to be showing up so im confused as to what the problem is

I tried reinstalling android studio, and the AVD itself, but nothing seemed to work. It seems the problem is apparent for all AVDs in fact, as I tried creating more virtual devices in android studio and testing them out, and the screen was still broken for all of them.

Comment: What Android Studio version are you using? Did you download one that fits to your chipset?

Comment: im using the latest version iguana 2023.2.1. How do I know which version fits my chipset?

Comment: I would try using a previous Android Studio version instead of the latest to see if the issue reproduces. If you are on a windows machine, then there is only one option.

Answer (score 0):

I can't yet post comments but the screen shot looks like random RAM.
In the emulator, extended controls, settings, there are some renderer options. I would try experimenting with those in this case.